# The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded

Tags: laravel-5, proxy, composer-php, vpn

I want to install a package for a Laravel chat app I'm making. When running "composer require foo/bar" I got the following error in the terminal:

```
In RemoteFilesystem.php line 515:

The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "proxy_user_name" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I'm using a VPN but it's still referring to my proxy  credentials which is supposed to not see because of the VPN.

When running "composer diagnose" I get this:

```
Lolo@lolo:/media/lolo/project_path/project_name$ 
composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "foobar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "foobar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "foobar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: WARNING
Unable to assess the situation, maybe packagist.org is down (The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "foobar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: WARNING

Unable to assess the situation, maybe github is down (The "https://api.github.com/repos/Seldaek/jsonlint/zipball/1.0.0" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "foobar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "foobar" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Checking disk free space: OK
Composer version: 1.6.3
PHP version: 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php7.2
```

What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to a bad proxy configuration. Try correcting your proxy or disable it (temporarily)  with

```
unset http_proxy;
unset https_proxy;
```

You could use redsocks when needing to go through a proxy.